# Possible migration from sound.SE

Tags: discussion, migration

I asked a question on [sound.SE](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/46971/25426) regarding the DC/AC output of an SPL meter.

I was hesitant regarding the best suited SE website. Since the question is pretty specific to audio, I choose *sound.SE*. But I didn't get much feedback there.

Do you think it would be better suited to *dsp.SE*?

FWIW, I made the same requests on [electronics.meta.SE](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7138/37038).

Comment: Tricky. It's a bit of all 3. Anyway, I posted a comment under your question - happy to help on sound.SE.

Comment: dsp.se and audio.se should be ok...

Comment: Hi @Fat32. I can't find any [audio.SE](http://audio.stackexchange.com/) ;)

Comment: sorry, it's sound.se ... ;-)